# Send HTTP GET Request After X Seconds, Service Gets Killed

Tags: android, android-service, android-networking

The title may seem duplicate but the question not about how to make the request, im sending a HTTP Get request from my android application to a web server after a specified interval using a service, the problem is it is stopped after i perform any other action on the device like play a video. The service looks like

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    final Context ctx=this;     
    Timer timer = new Timer(); 
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                   //perform GET here
            }, 0, 5000);    

    return Service.START_STICKY;    
}
```

any idea why such behaviour im experiencing even though im returning the `Service.START_STICKY`

Regards.

Comment: `like play a video` means from your activity or some other app?

Comment: No need of having any exclusive service for the same, it might be leaking. just simply submit a Timer task or Alarm task, this would be sufficient

Comment: @android-mantra some other app

Comment: try `return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);` instead `return Service.START_STICKY;`

Comment: have you tried using pending intents for this stuff???

Comment: @MOSO im not sure what you are talking about, can you provide an example...

Comment: If i got ur question right u need to run a method repeatedly after 5secs lets say scheduled time : then you can also take the approach of pending intents and broadcast receivers in which u can leave a pending intent at specified time and register a receiver and in onreceive you can perform you operation whether to start service or hit a werbservice. Look up http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-scheduling-recurring-tasks--mobile-5788 please let me know if it helps you in understanding the point.

Comment: @MOSO yes i got your point and thanks for the information, i'll give it a try...

Comment: an upvote cud be rather a better way of saying thanks :p

Comment: lol i was about to say thay plz post you comment mentioning `PendingIntent` as an answer and i sure will give you an upvote

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61110/discussion-between-moso-and-dakait).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment  you can take the approach of **PendingIntents** and **BroadcastReceiver** in which you can leave a pending intent at specified time and register a receiver and in onreceive you can perform you operation whether to start service or hit a werbservice.

---

Please go through http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-scheduling-recurring-tasks--mobile-5788
also http://www.sitepoint.com/scheduling-background-tasks-android/ for better understanding

Comment: @dakait glad to know it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try running your service in the 'foreground'. This way it is less likely to get killed.

Check out: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Comment: is this my only option? i dont want the user to be aware of the service

Comment: Not sure if your service is being killed. But it is likely due to the need of memory by the system. Check out the following page, a background-server is 3th on the kill-list. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Processes